# Load table saved with qsave in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown, reactable

I have a `reactable` table that I can display successfully on a web page if I embed the R Script in the R Markdown. However, I want to build the table in a separate R Script and load it into the R Markdown file.

In a separate R Script I build the reactable table.

```
> class(react_tbl)
[1] "reactable"  "htmlwidget"
```

The table appears in the RStudio Viewer.

Now I save the table:

```
qsave(react_tbl, react_table_filename)
```

To check, I do this in an R Script:

```r
react_tbl <- qread(react_table_filename)

react_tbl
```

The table appears in the viewer.

Now in R Markdown I do this and publish the page as I normally would using Blogdown > Github > Netlify:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

library("qs")

react_table_filename <- "<path to saved react table.qs>"
react_table <- qread(react_table_filename)
react_table

```
````

The result on the web page is lots of text:

```
## $x
## $x$tag
## <Reactable data="{&quot;etf_symbol&quot;:[&quot;CASH.TO&quot;,&quot;CSAV.TO&quot;,&quot;HISA.NE&quot;,&quot;NSAV.NE&quot;,&quot;PSA.T O&quot;],&quot;five_hundred&quot;:...
```

How do I get the actual reactable table to appear?

Comment: You probably need `library(reactable)` so that the appropriate print method is available.

Comment: I've expanded on my comment as an answer so others can make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the S3 system in R, special printing is done by `print` methods specific to the object.  As you saw, `reactable` creates objects with classes `"reactable"` and   `"htmlwidget"`, so R will look for a `print.reactable` function first, then `print.htmlwidget`, then `print.default`, and will use the first one it finds.  (In an R Markdown document auto-printing will actually look for `knit_print.reactable`, `knit_print.htmlwidget`, then `knit_print.default`, but that difference is not relevant here.)

In your R Markdown file, you load the object, but you didn't load the print functions.  Adding `library(reactable)` to the setup of the document should fix things.  `reactable` imports `htmlwidgets`, so that package (and a few others) will also be loaded automatically, and the print methods will be available.